# ASP.Net ListView Postback slow with lots of data in listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, request, postback, viewstate

I have a listview on my page that can display 10,000 or more rows.

There's a simple 'customer' drop down on the top of the page that does an auto-postback to change the data filter.  I've been trying to optimize this routine and I noticed that the majority of the time is spent transferring the ViewState from the client to server.

I've added EnableViewState="false" to the ListView control but it doesn't change it.  I've looked at the request in Fiddler and if the customer on screen has say 50 rows, the request content length is low - if they have 10,000 or something it's huge.

Anyone have a fix?

Comment: Your query could be the bottleneck.

Comment: The query is not the bottleneck... the postdata includes the viewstate which is the bottleneck verified by fiddler.

Comment: My bad. I missed this in your question: "but it doesn't change it." If your problem has been resolved by VinayC's suggestion, you need to give him credit by marking/checking his answer as accepted.

Comment: It appears that the the control level attribute does not solve the problem.  If I disable the ViewState for the entire page then it does disable the entire page, but that's not really the goal.  It would seem the ListView doesn't respond to the EnableViewState property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because data-bound control (including list view) would store their data-source into the view-state. So view-state will be large cause page size bloat.

One of the solution is to disable the view-state for list-view and bind it every time page posts back.

Even better solution is to do data store side paging i.e. if you are showing only 50 rows then fetch only 50 rows from the database. This is typically referred as custom paging in ASP.NET and you can find several examples for custom paging for your data access technology. For example,

custom paging uing Entity Framework & ObjectDataSource: http://geekswithblogs.net/Frez/articles/using-the-entity-framework-and-the-objectdatasource-custom-paging.aspx

You can use SQL Server ranking functions to do paging in a stored procedure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb445504.aspx

Comment: How do you disable the view state for listview?  I don't want paging because users do ctrl+f to find a specific record quickly.  15,000 records take ~3 seconds to load completely if you start from a small list and 30 seconds if you start from a big list.

Comment: @user771841, its control level property (preferably set in design mode). In .NET 4, use `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` in ListView tag. For prior versions, you need to use `EnableViewState="false". In prior version, you may have to fiddle with page level view-state.

Comment: For me setting ViewStateMode disabled on ListView only decreases ViewState by 20% (same as setting EnableViewState to false), where not rendering ListView decreases ViewState by nearly 100%. Do you know why that is? I've tried disabling ValidateRequest & EventValidation since I've read ViewState is used to support those features to no effect.

Comment: @Michael, not every state goes into a view-state bag, some of the necessary state gets stored in control-state bag and it cannot be disabled. Both view-state and control-state gets stored in a same hidden variable. My guess would be `DataKeyNames` and `DataKeys` may get stored in the control state so investigate from that perspective.